# Wso2 Cache Mediator Not returning expected response

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-esb

I am using cache Mediator for Token generation as the same token will be used by all methods. The problem, I have is the response is not picked from cache for different APIs.
Let me explain it below with example
If I have User method and I want to get List of users my url in API Manager will like
**/t/abc.com/context1/getUser**  (Get Method)
If I want to create User, then url will look like
**/t/abc.com/context1/User**  (Post Method)
If I want to getUserAttributes, then url will look like
**/t/abc.com/context2/getUserAttributes**  (Get Method). Please note the context over here is different from the previous 2

In all 3 cases the same In Sequence and Out Sequence files are used. Please note that all dynamic header values are removed before calling token generation method in the InSequence File. Below is the snippet of the same.

**InSequence** (inSeq_1.xml)

```
<script language="js"><![CDATA[var payload = mc.getPayloadJSON();
    mc.setProperty("jsonPayload",JSON.stringify(payload));]]></script>
    <payloadFactory media-type="json"> // to make payload empty
        <format/>
        <args/>
    </payloadFactory>

<property action="remove" name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" scope="axis2"/>
    <property action="remove" name="Cookie" scope="transport"/>
    <property action="remove" name="id" scope="transport"/>
    <cache collector="false" timeout="3600">
        <onCacheHit>
            <sequence key="gov:/apimgt/customsequences/in/inSeq_2.xml"/>
        </onCacheHit>
        <protocol type="HTTP">
            <methods>*</methods>
            <headersToExcludeInHash/>
            <responseCodes>.*</responseCodes>
            <enableCacheControl>false</enableCacheControl>
            <includeAgeHeader>false</includeAgeHeader>
            <hashGenerator>org.wso2.carbon.mediator.cache.digest.REQUESTHASHGenerator</hashGenerator>
        </protocol>
        <implementation maxSize="500"/>
    </cache>
    <send receive="gov:/apimgt/customsequences/out/outSeq_1.xml">
        <endpoint>
            <http method="get" uri-template="{uri.var.tokenGenerationUrl}"/>
        </endpoint>
    </send>
```

**OutSequence** (outSeq_1.xml)

```
<cache collector="true"/>
    <sequence key="gov:/apimgt/customsequences/in/inSeq_2.xml"/>
```

Here are the problems I am facing

- If I call getUser API twice, I get same token. But If I call getUser later followed by user (Post) I get different tokens, why is that? Should the caching be relevant to uri.var.tokenGenerationUrl rather than getUser or user (Post) methods?
- If I call getUser method followed by getUserAttributes (Please note both have different contexts and belong to different APIs in API Manager) both returns different Jwt.

NOTE: Even the To Header has been made to point tokenGenerationUrl.

Thereby can some one tell me what is wrong with the caching code?